# How to export QTable to .csv?

Tags: c++, qt, csv, export-to-csv, qtablewidget

How can I export values from a `QTableWidget` to .csv file or Excel file?

The program should collect values of three variables from a PLC. This PLC belongs to my company and have functions to do this collect.

Inserting items to `QTableWidget` .cpp:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushInsert_clicked()
{
/*
the program already is connected to plc, 
so I just have to choose the address inside of the plc. 
*/
    WORD wAddress = 50001;
    WORD value1 = 0;
    WORD value2 = 0;
    WORD value3 = 0;
    CollectVariables(wAddress,wValue);
    int ID = 0;
    string Name = "";
    int Age = 0;
    QTableWidget *table = ui->tableWidget;
    for(i=0;i<10; i++) {
        //id
        CollectVariables(wAddress+i, value1);
        table->setItem(i, 0, new QTableWidgetItem(value1));

        //name
        CollectVariables(wAddress+10+i, value2);
        table->setItem(i, 1, new QTableWidgetItem(value2));

        //age
        CollectVariables(wAddress+20+i, value3);
        table->setItem(i, 2, new QTableWidgetItem(value3));
        tabela->selectRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: The simplest way is to create a csv file. Excel will read this.

Comment: Another option would be to create a tab-separated text and write this into the [QClipboard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html). (With only one column per row like exposed in the sample code, there is in fact no tab to write but only `\n` for the end of each row.)

Comment: Ok dear @drescherjm, but how can I do this?

Comment: Here is a code example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487799/export-data-from-qtablewidget-to-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487799/export-data-from-qtablewidget-to-csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I used to "export" `QTableWidget` to .csv file (I can't export do excel) was to store the value of each space on the table to an array while inserting items to the table.

`QFile` was used to create the .csv file and `QTextStream` to insert values on it.

To improve the code I created a button to select the directory where this .csv file should be save.

Select Directory .cpp:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushSelectDir_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog directory;
    ui->lineEditDir->setText(directory.getSaveFileName(this,"Choose an directory"));
    dir_name = ui->lineEditDir->text();
}
```

Create .csv file .cpp:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushExportCSV_clicked()
{
    QFile data(dir_name+".csv");
    if (data.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append)) {
     }
    QTextStream output(&data);
    output <<"ID"<<","<<"Name"<<","<<"Age"<< '\n';
    for(i=0;i<10; i++) {   
        output << ID[i] <<","<< Name[i] <<","<< Age[i] << '\n';
    }
    data.close();
}
```